# MVC Shared partial view with a dropdown and separate controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

What I am after is having a partial view that hosts a dropdown list of all available languages in the system. This partial view will be used in many edit templates and will be loaded from a separate controller.

Following the articles and information on the net I have the following implementation:

ViewModel

```
public class LanguagesViewModel
{
    public int SelectedID { get; set; }

    public virtual SelectList Languages { get; set; }

    public LanguagesViewModel(int selectedID, IEnumerable<Language> languages)
    {
        SelectedID = selectedID;
        Languages = new SelectList(languages, "LanguageId", "Name");
    }
}
```

In the Shared folder I have a file: _LanguageDropDownList.cshtml with

```
@model XNETProductQuote.Web.Models.LanguagesViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedID, Model.Languages)
```

I have a LanguageController that has the following implementation

```
    public ActionResult GetAllLanguages()
    {
        var languages = service.GetAll();
        return PartialView("_LanguageDropDownList", new LanguagesViewModel(1, languages));
    }
```

So the above is meant to load the drop down list in that partial view so I can use it in other templates.

From a template that is loaded from a different controller (ApplicationSetting) I call the partial view using:

```
    @Html.Action("GetAllLanguages", "LanguageController")
```

This doesn't work. It throws an exception:
The controller for path '/ApplicationSetting/Edit/1' was not found or does not implement IController.

What is the correct implementation for such scenario?

Thanks

Comment: just correct html.action as ... @Html.Action("GetAllLanguages", "Language")

Comment: I knew it was something tiny... Thank you very much. So why is it not LanguageControler? The 4th override of the function says actionName, controllerName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asp.Net MVC when we make a new controller then `'Controller'` postfix is automatically attached to the Controller Name for ex:- in your case if you give `'Language'` name to the controller then controller's complete name will be like `'LanguageController'`,so where ever you want to give controller name you have to use only `'Language'` not `'LanguageController'` and one of the overloads of `@Html.Action()` is `ControllerName` which is only `'Language'` and not `'LanguageController'` ,So in your problem just change  `@Html.Action("GetAllLanguages", "LanguageController")` with  `@Html.Action("GetAllLanguages", "Language")` and your problem will be solved.